# why is my setter and getter methods not working?

Tags: java, methods, setter, getter

I have been looking at my source code and can't figure out what is wrong with it.
The problem I think is with the Circle class. When I call the mutators and accessors from
the DriverCircle class it's giving me the wrong output. For getDiameter it's just printing out 0s.

```
public class Circle{
    private double radius;  
    private double pi;
    private double diameter;
    private double circumference;
    private double area; 

    public Circle(){
        pi = Math.PI;
        radius = 0;
    }

    public Circle(double radius){
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    public void setDiameter(){
        diameter = (2 * radius);
    }
    public double getDiameter(){
        //diameter = 2 * radius;
        return diameter;
    }
    public void setCircumference(){
        circumference = (2 * pi * radius);
    }
    public double getCircumference(){
        //circumference = 2 * pi * radius;
        return circumference;
    }
    public double getArea(){
        //area = pi * Math.pow(radius, 2);
        return area;
    }
    public void setArea(){
        area = (pi * Math.pow(radius, 2));
    }
    public void setRadius(double radius){
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    public double getRadius(){
        return radius;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "The radius is " + radius;
    }
}
```

---

(The tester)...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CircleDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the radius: ");
        Circle[] circles = new Circle[10];
        Circle objectCircle = new Circle();
        objectCircle.setRadius(input.nextDouble());


        circles[1] = new Circle();
        circles[2] = new Circle(2.0);
        circles[3] = new Circle(3.5);
        circles[4] = new Circle(5.0);
        circles[5] = new Circle(0.0);
        circles[6] = new Circle(15);
        circles[7] = new Circle(25);
        circles[8] = new Circle(-7);
        circles[9] = new Circle(-10.0);

        System.out.println("Initial call to toString():");
        for (Circle c : circles)
            {System.out.println("\t" + c);}

        System.out.println("Call to getRadius (should be same as above):");
        for (Circle r : circles)
            {if (r != null)
                {System.out.println("\t" + r.getRadius());}}

        System.out.println("Call to getDiameter (should be twice the value shown above):");
        for (Circle d : circles)
            {if (d != null)
                {System.out.println("\t" + d.getDiameter());}}

        System.out.println("Calls to getCircumference:");
        System.out.println("\tShould be 2 * PI:  " + circles[1].getCircumference());
        System.out.println("\tShould be 0.0:  " + circles[5].getCircumference());

        System.out.println("\nCall to getArea:");
        System.out.println("\tShould be PI:  " + circles[1].getArea());
        System.out.println("\tShould be 0.0:  " + circles[5].getArea());

        System.out.println("Testing out the setRadius method:");
        for (int i = 0; i < circles.length / 2; i++)
            {if (circles[i] != null)
                {circles[i].setRadius(i);}}

        System.out.println("Call to toString after setting the first half of the objects:");
        for (Circle c : circles)
            {System.out.println("\t" + c);}
    }
}
```

Comment: Your setter methods should have parameters and use the parameters to set fields. Else they are not in fact setter methods. Your current setter methods should all be discarded.

Comment: You should not be storing diameter, circumference, and area as variables. Just calculate them in the getter method using radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setter methods should have parameters and use the parameters to set fields. Else they are not in fact setter methods. Your current setter methods should all be discarded, except perhaps `setRadius(...)`, and most of the calculations be done in the respective getter methods.

i.e., not

```
public void setCircumference(){
    circumference = (2 * pi * radius);
}

public double getCircumference(){
    //circumference = 2 * pi * radius;
    return circumference;
}
```

but rather

```
public double getCircumference(){
    return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

pi isn't initialized when you provide a value in constructor.  Further, storing pi as an instance member is a bit weird.  Just user Math.PI in your calculations.

Answer (score 1):

You never call `setDiameter()`. Your constructor sets the value of the radius, but it doesn't do anything about setting the diameter variable!

You may just want to rewrite `getDiameter()`:

```
public double getDiameter() {
    return 2.0 * radius;
}
```

Comment: I cut the setDiameter and just made a getDiameter method. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You constructed a Circle object, which sets the radius, but you never set the diameter.  Should probably call setDiameter() from the constructor.

Better yet, delete the setDiameter() method as it's completely unnecessary.  Simply make getDiameter() return 2*radius.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems.

First, and foremost, you don't set the value of `pi` if you use the double constructor.  You should also use the no-args constructor as well as set the value of your radius:

```
 public Circle(double radius){
    this(); // calls the no-args constructor
    this.radius = radius;
 }
```

Second, there's no explicit call to `setDiameter()`.  Funnily enough, that method is a misnomer - it should be calculated whenever the radius is nonzero. `setArea` is the same way - you're not passing anything in to that method call.  Here's what I would recommend:

- Rename `setDiameter` to `calculateDiameter` to make its intention clear.  The reason for the rename is to have this class follow [JavaBean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions) conventions with respect to set and get.
- In `public Circle(double radius)`, call `calculateDiameter()` immediately afterwards.
- Whenever `setRadius()` is called, either immediately follow it with a call to `calculateDiameter` or violate JavaBean conventions and call it immediately after the value is set.
- It's strongly encouraged to do the same thing for `getArea`, but I'll leave that portion as an exercise to the reader.

In code, a brief example:

```
 public Circle(double radius){
     this(); // calls the no-args constructor
     this.radius = radius;
     calculateDiameter();
 }

 public void setRadius(double r) {
     radius = r;
     calculateDiameter();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just setting the radius does not update every function that uses radius; you have to call those functions explicitly or else they remain at Java's default of 0.
I would also do any error checking at the Circle(radius) method; that way no negative numbers make it into the set of radii.